# When changing disabled input from true to false, why can I not click on the input?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that changes an input property from true to false. The dom and css update but I still cannot click on or use the input.

```
<input id="playerLocation" type="text" name="location" oninput="setPlayerLocation()" disabled="true">
```

```
.player-details input[disabled="true"] {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```
playerLocation.setAttribute('disabled', false);
```

Comment: Updated js with correct line

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `removeAttribute` for disabled.

```js
playerLocation.removeAttribute('disabled');
```

```html
<input id="playerLocation" type="text" name="location" oninput="setPlayerLocation()" disabled="true">
```